# Graph theory induction

Tags: graph-theory, induction, network

Prove by induction that if $G$ is a complete graph, which has n vertices, then the network $G$ has $n(n − 1)/2$ edges.

How do we go about induction with networks?

Comment: Do you mean [complete graphs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph&ved=2ahUKEwj49qTem5nmAhXXZSsKHdIJAzMQFjAiegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2hLkmg4bNUD8SCP0WiqsmO)?

Comment: Induction is on the number of vertices $n$.

Comment: Yes, edited. Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base case is trivial.

Imagine that we have a complete graph with $n-1$ vertices, then under the induction hypothesis, one must have $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$ edges. Let's add one more vertex that is connected to all other $n-1$ vertices. This results in $n-1$ supplemental edges, so in total
$$\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2} + n-1 = \frac{(n-1)(n-2) + 2(n-1)}{2} = \frac{(n-1)(n-2+2)}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
edges with $n$ vertices.